# How to calculate the correct time interval between two times that span two days in swift?

Tags: swift, date, calendar

I'm trying to get the correct time interval between two times that span two days (Overnight). Here is my code successfully printing out the difference between two times - however for my use case I need the ability to span overnight, how might I do this?

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    //This time represents (23:00, Aug 07) for example
    let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "23:00")!

    //This time represents (06:00, Aug 08) for example
    let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "06:00")!

    let elapsedTime = date2.timeIntervalSince(date1)
    print(abs(elapsedTime)/60/60)

    //prints 17.0
```

My desired result is a print out of 7, as that is the amount of hours between 23:00, Aug 7 and 06:00, Aug 8 - My current code is correctly showing me the interval between those two times (as if they were from the same day) but I am trying to work out how to account for when those times overlap two days. Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:

To give a more complete picture I have an object that has a start and and end date represented by a string:

```
Activity(startTime: "23:00", endTime:  "06:00")
```

I use some functions to turn those strings into dates:

```
func startDate(startTime: String) -> Date {
    let currentDate = Date().string(format: "dd-MM-yyyy")
    let myStartingDate = "\(currentDate) \(startTime)"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
    let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: myStartingDate)

    return startDate!
}

func endDate(endTime: String) -> Date {
    let currentDate = Date().string(format: "dd-MM-yyyy")
    let myEndingDate = "\(currentDate) \(endTime)"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
    let endDate = dateFormatter.date(from: myEndingDate)

    return endDate!
}
```

So my more complete workings look more like this:

```
func calculateTimeInterval(activity: Activity) {

let startHourDate = self.startDate(startTime: activity.startTime)
let endHourDate = self.endDate(endTime: activity.endTime)

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

//This time represents (23:00, Aug 07) for example
let date1 = startHourDate!

//This time represents (06:00, Aug 08) for example
let date2 = endHourDate!

let elapsedTime = date2.timeIntervalSince(date1)
print(abs(elapsedTime)/60/60)

}

//prints 17.0
```

Comment: How in your app do you know they're on separate days?  Your example just shows 2 times.

Comment: You should have `date` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I've added some more information that may help, I think the problem, as vacawama has eluded to, is that I haven't baked in specific dates - I'm new to using Dates so if someone could send me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: The time interval from "23:00" to "06:00" on the next day is “usually” 7 hours, but can also be 6 or 8 hours if the clocks are adjusted for daylight saving time. Therefore the problem is unclear without additional information. Is the start date always on the *current* day?

Comment: Yeah the start date would always be on the current day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a date part the only way to determine if the end time is past midnight is if the end time is less than the start time. If so your code can be changed to

```
var elapsedTime = date2.timeIntervalSince(date1)
if elapsedTime < 0 { 
    let date3 = date2 + 60 * 60 * 24
    elapsedTime = date3.timeIntervalSince(date1)
}
print(elapsedTime/60/60)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help - this calculation works in my situation (when only using strings) thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can write an Extension to Date like this:

```
extension Date {
    func hours(from date: Date) -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: date).hour ?? 0
    }
}
```

And just use it on any Date directly. This way you don't need DateFormatter at all. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help - that does look like a helpful extension and will come in handy for when I can write dates into my objects!